# Where to find GTFS realtime file

Tags: gtfs

I have been doing extensive research on GTFS and GTFS-Realtime. All I want to be able to do, is find out how late a certain bus would be. I can't seem to find where I can connect to, to properly search for a specific bus number. So my questions are:

1. Where/ how can I find the GTFS-Realtime file feed
2. How can I properly open the file, and make it location specific.

I've been trying to use http://www.yrt.ca/en/aboutus/GTFS.asp to download the file, but can't figure out how to open the csv file properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [What is GTFS-realtime?](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/), the GTFS-realtime data is not in CSV format. Instead, it is based on [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/):

> ### Data format
>
> The GTFS-realtime data exchange format is based on Protocol Buffers.
>
> Protocol buffers are a language- and platform-neutral mechanism for serializing structured data (think XML, but smaller, faster, and simpler). The data structure is defined in a gtfs-realtime.proto file, which then is used to generate source code to easily read and write your structured data from and to a variety of data streams, using a variety of languages – e.g. Java, C++ or Python.

Comment: Use the appropriate Protocol Buffers library for whatever language you're using.